# R Shiny: Output functions don't work within eventReactive()

Tags: r, button, shiny

I want to modify UI using `uiOutput()` and `plotOutput()` when the button is clicked. Everything works fine if it doesn't wait for the event and changes the content immediately. What should i change to make `output$body.on.button` having the same output as `output$body.immediately` when the button is clicked?

**server.R:**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$plot <- renderPlot({plot(1:5)})
  output$body.ui <- renderUI({tags$p('This works only within renderUI')})

  output$body.on.button <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    switch(
      input$select,
      "text" = 'This works within both functions',
      "ui" = uiOutput("body.ui"), # This doesn't work
      "plot" = plotOutput("plot") # This doesn't work
    )
  })

  output$body.immediately <- renderUI({
    switch(
      input$select,
      "text" = 'This works within both functions',
      "ui" = uiOutput("body.ui"), # This works
      "plot" = plotOutput("plot") # This works
    )
  })
})
```

**ui.R:**

```
library(markdown)

shinyUI(
  navbarPage(
    "Title",

    tabPanel(
      "First element",
      fluidRow(

        column(
          4,
          wellPanel(
            selectInput("select", "Select", c('text', 'ui', 'plot')),
            actionButton("goButton", "Go!")
          ) # end of wellPanel
        ), # end of column

        column(
          4,
          uiOutput("body.immediately")
        ), # end of column

        column(
          4,
          uiOutput("body.on.button")
        ) # end of column


      ) # end of fluidROw
    ) # end of tabPanel
  ) # end of navbarPage
) # end of shinyUI
```

I have also tried function `observeEvent()` but it didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because you can't have two outputs with the same ID. In your example "Text" works because it is just a text - not an output with an ID.

In the example below I've added three new outputs with unique IDs. uiOutput `body.on.button` also dynamically receives a specific output after clicking on a button.

---

You can try to remove this three lines

```
output$text2 <- renderText({ 'This works within both functions' })
output$body.ui2 <- renderUI({tags$p('This works only within renderUI')})
output$plot2 <- renderPlot({plot(1:10)})
```

and then change `IDs` within eventReactive from "text2" to "text" (similarly with the other two) to see that the outputs after clicking on a button are not going to be shown.

If you want to have, for example, two same plots, then you should create two `plotOutputs` with unique IDs and then use twice `renderPlot` functions which produce the same plots.

I hope this helps.

---

**Full example:**

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  # Create outputs with unique ID

  output$text <- renderText({ 'This works within both functions' })
  output$body.ui <- renderUI({tags$p('This works only within renderUI')})
  output$plot <- renderPlot({plot(1:5)})

  output$text2 <- renderText({ 'This works within both functions' })
  output$body.ui2 <- renderUI({tags$p('This works only within renderUI')})
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({plot(1:10)})


  # Save the selected type of the output and then pass it to renderUI via react()
  react <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    switch(
      input$select,
      "text" = textOutput("text2"),
      "ui" = uiOutput("body.ui2"), 
      "plot" = plotOutput("plot2") 
    )
  })

  output$body.on.button <- renderUI({
    react()
  })

  output$body.immediately <- renderUI({
    switch(
      input$select,
      "text" = textOutput("text"),
      "ui" = uiOutput("body.ui"), # This works
      "plot" = plotOutput("plot") # This works
    )
  })
})


  library(markdown)


ui <-shinyUI(
  navbarPage(
    "Title",

    tabPanel(
      "First element",
      fluidRow(

        column(
          4,
          wellPanel(
            selectInput("select", "Select", c('text', 'ui', 'plot')),
            actionButton("goButton", "Go!")
          ) # end of wellPanel
        ), # end of column

        column(
          4,
          uiOutput("body.immediately")
        ), # end of column

        column(
          4,
          uiOutput("body.on.button")
        ) # end of column


      ) # end of fluidROw
    ) # end of tabPanel
  ) # end of navbarPage
) # end of shinyUI
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks! The duplicity was created intentionally to make sure that it should work (but I didn't know that it can cause extra problem). The solution is in function `renderUI()`. It works fine now